# Is there a 'translation' for the URL query option of "SearchOrder="?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

In our XPages view controls, we compute a search string (xp:dominoView - xp:this.search) based on dropdown fields on the page, which works great.
But we found that this search returns the results sorted by relevance, and we'd prefer them to be kept in the view's sort order (usually, the first column is sorted ascending).
So, in the Notes client's FT search bar, you can specify this by changing the "Sort results by" flag to "Keep current order (sortable)", and this is also available as URL parameter by adding "SearchOrder=4" - but what would be the correct addition/wording to apply this to a "SELECT" statement resp. the XPages search we use?

Answer (score 0):

The view control has a couple of additional properties that you will need to set; sortOrder and sortColumn.

Also, I believe you need to make the sortColumn sortable on the actual view itself which is on the second tab of the Column properties, "Click on column header to sort".

```
<xp:dominoView
    var="view1"
    viewName="your view"
    sortOrder="ascending"
    sortColumn="your column name">
    <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.searchFilter;}]]>/xp:this.search>
</xp:dominoView>
```

Comment: Dear Gary, thanks for your help. I'm aware of the sortColumn & sortOrder properties, but as these settings might differ for each backend view, I'd still prefer to go for an addition in the search formula, which could then be applied for all cases.

Comment: Should have read your question more closely.  Have you considered making those custom properties?  In cases where I use the same viewPanel with other views as datasources, I've added a property for the sortColumn which can be static or computed depending on the need.

Comment: Also a good idea, might enhance the control with the custom properties - if there is no "SearchOrder=" / "Keep current order" equivalent. :)